# Is there a verb that is the antonym of the verb "to listen"?

Tags: vocabulary

I've been looking for a single word that exactly means "to stop listening", but I haven't found anything. Is there such a word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many instances, "ignore" will work for you.

From Dictionary.com:

```
ignore
 verb (used with object), ignored, ignoring.
1.
to refrain from noticing or recognizing:
to ignore insulting remarks.
```

Informally, from comments below, there are these options:

- tune out
- drift off
- zone out

Comment: Yeah, it will +1, but isn't there a word directly related to "not to listen", even if olde?

Comment: Checking [Thesaurs.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/listen), none of the antonyms is specific to our auditory sense.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I came here with the hope of finding a word even if really archaic

Comment: Another phrase, though slang, is to "zone out" and yet another is to "drift off"

Comment: But that's like falling asleep or something

Comment: @Mr. Derpinthoughton In one sense, yes. Not in the sense TecBrat means. 'Tune out' is another option if you can put up with a multi-word verb.

Comment: Oh tune out sounds totally appropriate